# Showing the time remaining between two Date columns as a perentage

Tags: calculated-column-formula, formula

I've got two columns 'Contract Commencement Date' and 'Contract End Date' and I'm trying to show the time remaining as a percentage in a third column.

Using Flow I've got a field to show todays date, and I'm using some JSON to colour code the field but I'm not getting the correct percentage. I've set the Percentage Test column up as calculated field with the following formula: =TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date] as a percentage. Where am I going wrong

[image: Screen Grab of the lists]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your TodayDate column is updated automatically every day (which should then also re-trigger your calculated field), then your formula should correctly calculate the total number of days that have elapsed since the Start of the Contract.  I will point that this means if the `[Contract Commencement Date]` is in the future, then your formula would return a negative number.  You can avoid that by changing the calculation to `MIN(0, TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date])`.  However, this still only gives you total elapsed days, not a percentage.
If you want a percentage,  you want to divide the total days elapsed by the total number of days in the contract  The total days in the contact would be `([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date])`, so your total formula would be:

```
=MIN(0, TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date])/([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date])
```

Comment: Thanks @willman. I'm getting there. I put the formula in and I'm getting 0% back in the percentage test field?

Comment: I'm really close! I took out the =MIN(0, and put the Number if decimal places to 0 and now the percentages are coming out as 22.54853342203838% and 72..98878342203838% how do I round it up to just the whole number?

Comment: `ROUNDUP` or `ROUNDDOWN` where the first parameter is the value to round and the second parameter is the number of digits after the decimal point.  So, to round up to whole number `=ROUNDUP(TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date]/([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date]), 0)`

Comment: Thanks @willman. I popped that it and now all the percentages have come out as wither 4384400% or 4378900% ?

Comment: Found this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDUP-function-A92985D9-F99A-4ED4-9FD4-AD6E1D6F10B7 

There's 13 numbers to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: last post for today! I've put in =ROUNDUP((TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date])/([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date]),0)   and I'm getting 100% and 700% on some items but then on one item I changed the Commencement Date to Today is coming up at 0%  ?

Comment: 0% would be corrected if today is the start date, the formula measures what percent is elapsed/complete.  You may want the top part of division to wrapped in `MIN` otherwise things will be funny when the commencement in the future. Min will force future starts to also be zero.

Comment: Hi @willman You're quite right, the 0% is starting to show at 2.1111xxxx% percent.

I get the percentage with extra unneeded numbers after the decimal point with the formula: =(TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date])/([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date])

but if I add:

=MIN(0,TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date])/([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date])  it screws the percentage up. Any ideas?

Comment: LOL, it just occurred to me, if we're trying to avoid negative numbers in the numerator, MIN(0, -3), would equal -3.  We need to change that to `MAX`, since that will only return 0 when the numerator would otherwise be negative.

Comment: Thanks @willman. How would I format that? 

=MAX(0,doesn't really have any effect. neither does =MAX(9

Comment: It's formatted the same way as the `MIN` -- `=MAX(0,TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date])/([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date])`

Comment: That didn't have any effect